# Clear list with jquery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, list

I have two lists. The first has some items and click over one of them should show another list. 
This list should change every time I click one of the item of the first because it has other datas. For example : 
in a list of job orders I want show the users belonging to the relative job order when i click over it. I can do it now, but I can't clear the list. That's the code:

```
var refreshList = function(id) {
  // ..Ajax service..
  $.get("request",
        {
    id: id
  }, function(obj) {
    $("#userList").empty();
    var $ul = $( '<ul id="userList" class="list-group">' );
    for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
      $ul.append('<li class="list-group-item">'+ obj[i].description + '</li>');
    }
    $ul.appendTo( '#userListContainer' );
  });
}
```

This is the service that fires `onclick=""` in the item of the first list. It makes an ajax request, it returns an array of objects and it creates the second list. Using `$("#userList").empty();` I can clear the list but the `DOM` still creates the `<ul>` tag every time i click over one item. Is is possible just clearing the list and replace it with new datas?

Comment: Use [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) instead of `empty`. Or do not create new `ul` each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple elements with the same ID in one document is invalid HTML. Also, as is, you're creating a new `ul` each time. Why not, after emptying, append the new `li`s to the *existing* `ul`, rather than to a whole new `ul`?

```
var refreshList = function(id) {
  // ..Ajax service..
  $.get("request", {
    id: id
  }, function(obj) {
    var $ul = $("#userList"); // ensure it already has class="list-group"
    $ul.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      $ul.append('<li class="list-group-item">' + obj[i].description + '</li>');
    }
    // no need to append the ul, should already be appended
  });
}
```

Or, with more modern syntax and only `append`ing to the DOM once:

```
var refreshList = function(id) {
  $.get("request", {
    id: id
  }, function(obj) {
    var $ul = $("#userList");
    $ul.empty();
    $ul.append(
      obj.map(({ description }) => `<li class="list-group-item">${description}</li>`).join('')
    );
  })
}
```

Comment: I tried both solutions. I've got some problem with the second one but the first works well. Thank you so much. I was used to use AngularJs and its two-waydata binding to do this kind of stuffs. Easier imo. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `appendTo()` you can use `html()` or `innerHtml`

```
var refreshList = function(id) {
  // ..Ajax service..
  $.get("request",
        {
    id: id
  }, function(obj) {
    //$("#userList").empty();
    var $ul = $( '<ul id="userList" class="list-group">' );
    for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
      $ul.append('<li class="list-group-item">'+ obj[i].description + '</li>');
    }
    $('#userListContainer').html($ul);
  });
}
```

> or if you wish to use `appendTo()` then remove userList before append, using `.remove()`

```
var refreshList = function(id) {
  // ..Ajax service..
  $.get("request",
        {
    id: id
  }, function(obj) {
    //$("#userList").remove();
    var $ul = $( '<ul id="userList" class="list-group">' );
    for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
      $ul.append('<li class="list-group-item">'+ obj[i].description + '</li>');
    }
    $ul.appendTo( '#userListContainer' );
  });
}
```